# How to I have a default object property and have the option of setting it?

Tags: python, object, methods, properties

I've been reading about [setting object properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), but I was confused and haven't succeeded in attempts.

I want create a new object.  i.e. `Thissle = yt_video()`

Then, if I run `Thissle.url` I want a randomly selected url, and I want the option of putting my own url in parenthesis `Thistle.url("http...")` or if I use `Thissle.url = "http..."` I don't get any output

```
class yt_video (object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__url = self.url

    @property
    def url (self): #returns a random url from the two
        url1 = 'https://youtu.be/WaGRTixwkSQ'
        url2 = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6FhCd_HO_AD-22-Csv-vYlhLoKlAY3Zt'
        self.__url = random.choice([url1, url2])
        logger.debug('Running test on url...%s',self.__url)
        return self.__url
    @url.setter
    def url(self, value):
        self.__url = value
```

Right now I get the random url with Thissle.url and I can create the object - but I can't set the value manually. Nothing returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use setter property, you should assign to the property isntead of trying to call it.

```
video = yt_video()
video.url = 'http://....'  # <---
```

---

**UPDATE**

`url` property always returns random url. Currently there's no way to access `__url` attribute outside class.

I suggest to getter, setter simply return / set the attribute.

For example:

```
class yt_video(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.set_random_url()

    def set_random_url(self):
        url1 = 'https://youtu.be/WaGRTixwkSQ'
        url2 = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=...'
        self.__url = random.choice([url1, url2])

    @property
    def url(self):
        return self.__url

    @url.setter
    def url(self, value):
        self.__url = value

video = yt_video()
video.url = 'http://example.com'
print(video.url)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.

There's something else wrong. I got `AttributeError: 'yt_video' object has no attribute '_yt_video__url'
[Finished in 0.824s]`

Comment: @StackJohan, the error you are getting is because of the `url = random.choice([url1, url2])` statement in `def url (self)`. It should be `self.__url = random.choice([url1, url2])`

Comment: @falsetru I updated the code. There are no errors, but nothing outputs

Comment: @yeniv That helped. No errors, but now I just don't have anything output `[Finished in 0.09s]`

Comment: @StackJohan, I updated the answer. Please check it out.

Comment: @falsetru One other issue - where would I put the logger statement?

Comment: @StackJohan, It's up to you. I would put it after the last statement of `set_random_url`.

Comment: @falsetru I spoke too soon :(  I expected video.url to print the random url - but it prints `<property object at 0x0000015618C24BD8>
[Finished in 0.122s]`  - but I can still set the url by video.url = "".

Comment: Hmm, weird. There's just something going on with my coding program. I refreshed the window and now it's working fine again -__-